# schedule command with "at" after reboot

Tags: linux, scheduled-task, at

I'm trying to schedule a command to run only once with `at`. But the server is prone to reboot at least once every day.

I already tried to schedule a command with at` to be executed in 24 hours, but it wasn't executed.

how can I get `at` to remember the scheduled task, even after the reboot?

Comment: I'm scratching my head over this one.  `at` stores its commands in /var/spool/cron/atjobs.  They should still be there after a reboot, unless a shutdown job is cleaning them out.  Can you confirm that an `at` job is present in /var/spool/cron/atjobs before reboot and missing afterwards?

Comment: no, there is no atjobs-file in /var/spool/cron/. but there is a /var/spool/atjobs/ path which contains 3 files

Comment: That's what I meant.  So after you reboot, are those files still there, and is atd running?

Comment: I can't manually reboot the system to find out - but when I logged in today, atd wasn't running at all. I did a "chkconfig atd on" now. hopefully that will fix the problem